# Table heading multicolumn problem

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have the following code, which needs 2 sub-columns in the last main column. I have written code as follows:

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries First} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries Characteristics} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries Implemented in}\\ A&B \\ \hline
    a & b & c & d \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The result is

[image]

I want the "A" and "B" as sub-column within the "Implemented in" column.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  You can use `\\ && A&B` instead of `\\ A&B`.  The first two `&&` are to skip over the first two columns.  You should also have a look at the `booktabs` package.

Comment: It worked thanks!. You can move it as an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `\\ && A&B` instead of `\\ A&B`.  The first two `&&` are to skip over the first two columns.

[image]

### Notes:

- As per Bernard'scmment,  [the `multirow` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow) was used to vertically center the first two headers across the two rows.
- As per @AlanMunn's comment, `\cline{3-4}` can be used to draw lines across specified columns.

---

However, I would strongly recommend you have a look at [the `booktabs` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs) for tables:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries First} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Characteristics} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries Implemented in}\\ \cline{3-4}
    && A&B \\ \hline
    %------
    & b & c & d \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `booktabs`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c l c c}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries First} & 
    \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries Characteristics} & 
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries Implemented in}\\ \cmidrule(lr){3-4}
    && A&B \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-4}
    %------
    & b & c & d \\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to draw a line, only under "Implemented in". I tried `\hline`. It underlines the whole row.

Comment: Also, is it possible to align "First" and "Characteristics" equally spaced between the top and bottom lines?

Comment: You can use `\cline{n-m}` where *n* and *m* are the first and last columns under which you want the line.

Comment: @Sathish Krishnan: load the multirow package and replace  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\bfseries First} with  \multirow{2}{*}{\bfseries First}. Same for "Characteristics". Also replace \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries Implemented in} with \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries Implemented in}

Comment: @Bernard:  Thanks. Have incorporated your suggestions in the answer.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Thanks. Have incorporated your suggestions in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

With the new package `tabularray` is simple. Using it you need to insert one ampersand for each column, i.e. in your case three ampersands per row:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
     \centering
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
             colspec={c l Q[c,wd=3.3em] Q[c,wd=3.3em]},
             row{1}={font=\bfseries},
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c} First   
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{c} Characteristics 
        &  \SetCell[c=2]{c} Implemented in 
            &       \\
    \midrule
    &   & A & B     \\ 
    \midrule
    & b & c & d     \\
 1  & 2 & 3 & 4     \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]